# Cannot created a New Database Name in PhpMyAdmin -1102 error

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Have tried to create a new Database Name on the PhpMyAdmin(xampp)  but turns Unsuccessful 
The return error message was - "1102- Incorrect Database Name 'registration'"

[image]

Comment: You have a space at the end of registration. You cannot have spaces in the database name.

Comment: which space you mentioned here?, if i entered a new database name in the database fields under Create database  the error message pops up as shown

Comment: check carefully you have `'registration '` instead of `'registration'`

Answer (score 2):

By mistake you have given a space after typing registration. Edit your database name without giving any space and press Create.